# Adapted from English

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> Many Urdu plays are **adapted from English**

I think it should be

> Many Urdu plays are adapted from the English literature.

Comment: Could you please add more detail to explain why you think it should be the second sentence?  Otherwise the question may be closed.

Comment: As it stands the second version isn't valid (not sure if it's actually "ungrammatical", but no native speaker would ever be likely to use it). But you *can* include just the article *(Many Urdu plays are adapted from **the** English)* - that would be a "stylised, academic" usage equivalent to *...the English **originals / versions / etc.** [of the plays]* or similar. By the same token you'll often see things like *Translated from the Russian* instead of plain *Translated from Russian* - the effect of the article being to "aggrandize" the original (as a great work of literature, for example).